# How to attach actions from my controller to the TabControl?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, tabcontrol

I use Devexpress in the ASP.NET MVC project. Now, I try to make the `TabControl` to it loads my pages as tab content. Below that I have at this moment:

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
@using PM.Resources.Strings;


@Html.DevExpress().TabControl(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "CatalogTabControl";
    settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

    settings.Tabs.Add(tab =>
    {
        tab.Name = "TabCompetences";
        tab.Text = Headers.Competences;
    });
}).GetHtml()
```

But I can't understand and find (or just understand) how to listen tab selection (set callback) to update page content?

Comment: Have you want to update tab contents when changing tabs? If so, `ActiveTabChanged` client-side event may suitable for your issue (since it is still unclear what action you need to take with given tab strip control).

Comment: Not sure, but can you use the NavigateUrl property on the tab?

Comment: No, I'll try. Thank for comments.